# Detect focus on an input (onfocusin) even id the element does not exists in the dom yet with vanilla (plain) javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']").forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener('onfocusin', () => {
            alert("was focused!!!");
        });
    });
```

The problem with these is that only works when the element exists. If some element is added to the dom after this code is called, it will not be added any event listener.

How can I detect the `onfocusin` event even if the element does not exist yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the event listener on a parent element that contains all (future) inputs (for example, the document itself). The event will "bubble up" from the input. Inside the handler you will need to check if the target is actually the element you want:

```
 document.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
   const target = e.target;
   if (target.tagName == "INPUT" && target.type == "text") {
        alert("was focused!!!");
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is supported by most modern browsers, you can hook the dom changed event therein

```
var observeDOM = (function(){
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  return function( obj, callback ){
    if( !obj || !obj.nodeType === 1 ) return; 

    if( MutationObserver ){
      // define a new observer
      var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
          callback(mutations);
      })
      obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
    }

    else if( window.addEventListener ){
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);  //<----------****
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
    }
  }
})();
```

You can add your own logic in DOMNodeInserted() function:

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to jQuery or does it have to be plain Javascript?

In case you can use jQuery you can do:

```
$(document).on("focusin","input[type='text']",function(event) {
    alert('element was focused', {event:event});
    // let element = $(event.currentTarget); 
});
```

See RoToRa's answer for plain JS

Comment: Has I said in the question, "vanilla (plain) javascript"

Comment: @RicardoRocha added reference to RoToRa's answer for the plain version

Answer (score 0):

### Angular/Typescript version

Based on the [@RoToRa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931400/5148197) and because I want to use this in an angular/typescript application, here how to use the @RotoRa's code in typescript:

```
document.addEventListener('focusin', (event: Event) => {
     const target: HTMLElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
     if (target instanceof HTMLInputElement && target.type === 'text') {
          console.log("element was focused)
     }
});
```